# Do we need to make changes to the eTA (Canada)?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, canada, eta, japanese-citizens

My girlfriend stated that she was unemployed on her eTA application, but she is currently working as a dispatcher at a phone case company. She has also been hired as a kindergarten teacher, which she will start on April 1, 2023. Her current eTA did not cause any issues, even though she stated that she was unemployed, but she was asked about her occupation. Should we keep the current eTA or change it?

Comment: Can you let us know what country the eTA is for? At least Canada and Australia use the term.

Comment: Given your previous questions I have edited your question to make it clear we are talking about a eTA for Canada. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: She is from Japan and eta for canada

Answer (score 5):

A new Canadian eTA is only required if the original eTA expires (or is cancelled by the government), or a passport other than the one associated with the original eTA is used for travel.

> **[Period of validity](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/eng/regulations/sor-2002-227/FullText.html)**
>
> 12.05 (1) An electronic travel authorization is valid for a period of five years from the day on which it is issued to the applicant or
> until the earliest of the following days, if they occur before the end
> of that period:
>
> - (a) the day on which the applicant’s passport or other travel document, in respect of which the electronic travel authorization was
>   issued, expires,
> - (b) the day on which the electronic travel authorization is cancelled,
> - (c) the day on which a new electronic travel authorization, in respect of the same passport or the same travel document, is issued to
>   the applicant, or
> - (d) the day on which the country or authority referred to in paragraph 190(1)(a) that issued the passport or other travel document
>   in respect of which the electronic travel authorization was issued is
>   no longer referred to in that paragraph.

---

One may want to apply for a new eTA, but is not required to, if information related to their admissibility (e.g. criminal convictions) changes if they would like to get their admissibility reassessed before flying to Canada. In all cases, an admissibility determination may be carried out at the border.